# Web scraping, need to parse further

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, soap

I am trying to parse a page by the following link: https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=&fromSearchLine=true&st=searchVacancy&text=cisco

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
URL = "https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=&fromSearchLine=true&st=searchVacancy&text=cisco"
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

scrape = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"bloko-link HH-LinkModifie"})
```

I maneged to get inside the block of the block I am interested in and save it to the `scrape` variable. But, I noticed that It has extra information.

The output looks like:

```
>>> scrape[1]
<a class="bloko-link HH-LinkModifier" data-position="1" data-qa="vacancy-serp__vacancy-title" data-requestid="1613425264373c08a0e137d1f1d147e0" data-totalvacancies="1962" href="https://hh.ru/vacancy/42150333?query=cisco" target="_blank">Ведущий инженер сетевой инфраструктуры ЦОД (Cisco)</a>
>>> scrape[2]
<a class="bloko-link HH-LinkModifier" data-position="2" data-qa="vacancy-serp__vacancy-title" data-requestid="1613425264373c08a0e137d1f1d147e0" data-totalvacancies="1962" href="https://hh.ru/vacancy/41879000?query=cisco" target="_blank">Сетевой инженер Cisco/Pre-sale (направление сети Cisco, системная интеграция)</a>
>>> scrape[3]
```

Basically, I am interested in letters between the target="_blank" and </a. Could you tell me please if SOAP offers me a way to extract that portion of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
}
url = "https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=&fromSearchLine=true&st=searchVacancy&text=cisco"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

scrape = [a.getText() for a in soup.find_all("a", class_="bloko-link HH-LinkModifier")]
print("\n".join(scrape))
```

Output:

```
Эксперт технической поддержки Cisco UC
Ведущий инженер сетевой инфраструктуры ЦОД (Cisco)
Сетевой инженер Cisco/Pre-sale (направление сети Cisco, системная интеграция)
Системний адміністратор (Cisco)
Продакт-менеджер Cisco (стажер)
Системный администратор
Инженер лаборатории (Cisco Systems)
Менеджер по продажам (Cisco Systems)
Cisco Voice engineer
Аккаунт менеджер (Cisco Systems)
Сетевой инженер
Стажер Cisco
and more ...
```